# End Program - WMS Idle

Tags: windows, shutdown

When I turn off my computer there is a dialog box that says End Program - WMS Idle. This appears everytime I turn my computer off...

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](http://forums.techarena.in/windows-xp-support/702909.htm) (amongst others) implicates Nero as the cause of the problem, but it also references this [Microsoft support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/921113) which blames Windows Communicator 2005.